# How to optimally return whether a phrase has occurred in a stream of words?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stream

There is a stream of words coming, which is significantly large. As the words keep coming, it can be asked to tell whether a *phrase* has occurred in the stream already seen or not? *There may be multiple such queries at different times.*

For instance, suppose the stream of words seen till now is:

> hello world here is another programmer

Then, it's asked to tell whether the phrase `here is another` has been seen or not, which is true in this case.

How to optimally return this?

I have been trying to work upon the solution using construction of graphs and doing BFS when queried, but it poses 2 problems:

- First, to be optimal, I also have to store the *words => address of node in the graph* pair in a hash-table.
- Second, when there is cycle, then the algorithm fails as in the stream: `a b c d a b c e`

Suggest an optimal solution for the requirement.

Comment: Would you consider any of these solutions optimal? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606581/find-repeated-word-in-infinite-stream-of-words

Comment: @OzzieGooen The question you mentioned is, although you may find related, is completely different as it's asking to report duplicates which can be handled only by using hash-tables.

Comment: Since you don't know what the query phrase will be, if there is only one query then it doesn't make sense to assume you have a stream; you have to remember all the data you have seen so far.  Or maybe you get multiple queries at various times, while the stream is still coming in?  That I could understand I guess.  Or maybe you want to do something like continual linear time work as the stream is coming in, so that you can solve the problem much faster than O(n) when the query comes in?

Answer (score 1):

You can look up "online construction of suffix trees" and find an algorithm by Ukkonen which processes a stream and always has a suffix tree for your stream ready after each character is processed, and the running time and space is O(n) if you have seen n characters so far.  Then, each time you are given a query phrase, you can use substring matching algorithm for suffix trees to find all matches for a given query phrase, and the query time is optimal O(m) to find a match if your query phrase has length m.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the OP's question.

Comment: I am sorry, can you explain how suffix trees will be helpful here? If you are hinting towards string matching, then how will it reduce the complexity of the query to the length of the query string?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are receiving the text body to search in a streaming manner, it doesn't make sense to "preprocess" the text for more efficient search.  Here is an efficient implementation in C# that deals with the text to be searched in a streaming manner.

```
static IEnumerable<int> Search(string text, string query)
{
    var D = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    //Loop invariant: D[i] == j iff text[i..(i+j)] == query[0..j]
    //                for all pairs (i,j) in D
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        foreach (var k in D.Keys.ToList())
        {
            D[k] = D[k] + 1;
            if (D[k] == query.Length)
            {
                yield return k;
                D.Remove(k);
            }
            else if (text[i] != query[D[k]])
            {
                D.Remove(k);
            }
        }
        if (text[i] == query[0])
            D.Add(i, 0);
    }
    foreach (var k in D.Keys)
    {
        if (D[k] == query.Length)
            yield return k;
    }
}
```

A streaming-based version can be implemented as follows. I think the end-of-stream case might not be handled right, but you should be able to adapt the idea to something that works even in that edge case.

```
class SearcherState
{
    public Dictionary<int, int> D = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    public int i = 0;
}

static Func<char, int?> Searcher(string query)
{
    var state = new SearcherState();
    return c =>
    {
        int? result = null;
        foreach (var k in state.D.Keys.ToList())
        {
            state.D[k] = state.D[k] + 1;
            if (state.D[k] == query.Length)
            {
                result = k;
                state.D.Remove(k);
            }
            else if (c != query[state.D[k]])
            {
                state.D.Remove(k);
            }
        }
        if (c == query[0])
            state.D.Add(state.i, 0);
        state.i++;
        return result;
    };
}
```

Comment: This takes at least Omega(n) time where the stream has produced n characters so far.  For large n and rather small length queries, having n in the query time every time a query comes in is unacceptable.

Comment: @user2566092 The question is posed such that the text to be searched is being streamed through and searched as it is streamed. You can't, say, build a trie ahead of time. Furthermore, there only seems to be one query string specified. The OP doesn't say that there will multiple queries.

Comment: imo there can be multiple queries at different times, according to the way the question was written.  But if there is only one query, and if the user doesn't mind waiting a while to get the answer when the query comes in, even though there were cpu cycles available that were wasted while the stream was coming in, then i agree your answer is acceptable.  imo the real question is how fast the stream is coming in, so that it can be determined whether an online linear time pre-processing can keep up and then make queries basically take no time when they come in.

Comment: @user2566092 See the second part of my answer for how you could exploit the online nature of the problem. You create a `var searcher = Searcher("here is another");` and then you repeatedly call `searcher(c)` each time a new character comes in from your text stream. If `searcher(c)` returns something other than `null`, it means that a match has been found at the returned index. The point of providing the offline `Search` method first was to show how the same algorithm would be done in an offline manner before showing the online version.

Comment: @TimothyShields +1 for the code. Sorry, if you got it wrong, but, my question was *as the stream comes in, queries may be posed.* That's why I was trying to store the stream with a hash-table corresponding to the graph.